# How to assign TemplatedParent Content property to a variable?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, .net-6.0

I have this code where the user clicks on a List Box Item and I try to get the Content property of TemplatedParent assigned into a variable to check later, but I get this error:

[image: Code preview]

[image]

[image]

How can I assign the content value to a variable?

Comment: You have to pass a DependencyProperty to `GetValue` so replace `Content` with `ContentControl.ContentProperty`

Comment: That's amazing, it worked! You could put this as an answer so I can mark it as the correct answer. Thank you!

Comment: Done, glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass a DependencyProperty to `GetValue` so replace *Content* with `ContentControl.ContentProperty`